# permanent storage of PHP variables?

Tags: php, variables, storage

Is it possible to store permanent variables in PHP, i.e. final unmodifiable variables, but which can be read by all users requesting a page?

E.g. I would need to use a dictionary on a page, starting with a big (invariant) word list. What is the best way to do this?

- Converting the word list to a tree on-the-fly on every page load is a total waste of compute resources and requires several seconds per page load.
- Putting the tree in the file system as subfolders and use `file_exists()` is fast enough but uses 4KB per word, which is a total waste of disk space.
- Putting the words in a database is unworkable as I need thousands of lookups per page load.

What would be the proper way to store this dictionary?

Comment: `Is it possible to store permanent variables in PHP`? Do you know anything about sessions? or mysql?

Comment: What do you mean? I explicitly mention why a database (e.g. MySQL) is not usable, and I do not see how sessions can be applied here (as variables in a session are only available to the user of that session, AFAIK).

Comment: If you leave the problem of the storage and loading of that dictionary aside for a moment: Which form would that dictionary have if it would exist (in code, e.g. an array or object) and please provide the code how the usage would look like. This should make things more clear. E.g. why 4kb per word?

Comment: Do you want the final and unmodifieble variable to be set by users ?

Comment: @hakre, 4kb would be the block size of a particular filesystem. actual space consumed per file is always a multiple of the block size, and I assume the OP wanted 1 word per file.

Comment: You regarded three solutions, but you forgot an important and useful solution for your case. It is xml documents. parsing xml is quicker than parsing text files, and more solid than file system.

Comment: @The COMPLETE PHP Newbie: No, I will set it, it is identical for all users.

Comment: @hakre: my idea there was to use the folder tree structure to store the word tree, e.g. the existence of the word `horse` in the dictionary would be saved as the existence of `folder/h/o/r/s/e/_`.

Comment: @sємsєм: very good idea. I'll look into that as an option.

Comment: @user1111929: Yes that was your idea about the store. But as I commented, leaving the store aside, how would the dictionary look like in PHP?

Comment: @hakre: currently I'm using an object `Node`, where each node has a `Node parent`, a `Node[26] children` (one for each letter in the alphabet), and and `int[] current` to store the current word if it is in the dictionary (and null if it isn't).

Comment: And, in case the above would not be clear, looking up if a word is in the dictionary, is done as follows: `curr=root;` `for (ch in word) { if (curr.children[ch]!=null) curr=curr.children[ch]; else return false; }` `return curr.curr==word;` But often other accesses to this tree are needed, in particular to check if there are words "starting with ...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

memcached is very popular in php as a way to keep stuff in memory that can be accessed by many processes
http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

a similar solution could be to use an sqlite shared memory database
http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Yes, in memory is the way to go. If you use the right data structure and a good search algorithm then it should be blazing fast.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that your page is supposed to hold a dictionary for an invariant list of words. If the list of words is invariant, **and** if the resulting dictionary is invariant also, then why not cache the whole content of the page? This would allow constant access time for all users.

A common pattern for this use case is to compute the list of words into a key, suited for a lookup in a datastore such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/). Performance seems to be important to you, and in this case, one single read-roundtrip to the datastore, and virtually no processing is required to display the page.

If users can interact with the word list, that would be the time to invalidate the cached page. There again, one single write-roundtrip to the datastore is required.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need, but I never heared of memcached before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think a NoSQL Database, like MongoDB is very suitable for your needs. More info:

- http://www.mongodb.org/
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a database handling "thousands of lookups per load"? That kind of what it was designed to do, you know.

Implement a database solution, with proper indexing, and you'll be fine.

Comment: More importantly, assuming the code to fetch from the DB is reasonable, it should be absolutely no problem to fetch 1000's of ITEMS from the database. For example this page: http://www.planetcatfish.com/catelog/family.php?family_id=4
fetches from species, genera, family, my_fish and images table, and produces a page with 1150 items. And it takes a fraction of a second locally on my machine - it will probably take a lot longer to send the page to you, but that's a different matter. 

Give sql a decent amount of RAM, and it will be fast. If you keep the whole DB in memory, you need more.

Comment: I meant thousants of *queries*, not items. I'm doing sort of a backtracking algorithm and every time I need to decide to continue a branch or not, it needs a separate dictionary lookup. So it's really thousands of queries, every time with a 1-item return value.